# Clicking on green reputation button does not make it go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

Clicking on green reputation button does not make it go away for example mine reads +15 in green at the top of the page and it will not reset. Is there a bug at the moment? is there a way to make it reset?

Comment: Know issue http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268957/792066

Comment: Yes, has been there since the tests. Some people (incl. me) aren't getting the rep popup.

Answer (score 1):

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away - this should now be resolved.