# Changing reputation; somtimes it goes up, then down again

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Maybe related to the recent bug, mentioned [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11794/clicking-on-green-reputation-button-does-not-make-it-go-away), but I noticed my reputation sometimes unexpectedly increases (you never know what you did :), but then goes back to what you actually *should* have at that moment. At first I thought my mind was playing tricks on me, but see the screenshots of two windows at the same moment. (The lowest is correct).

Is anyone else experiencing the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is not someone accepting and un-accepting an answer?

Comment: @Rinzwind I cannot exclude, but it happened to me three times today, first with 10 points difference (which is hard to revert) and now with 15. If it would be something like that, I should be able to see it in my rep history, which is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should explain everything:

```
VoteTypeId CreationDate            DeletionDate            TargetUserId TargetRepChange
---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ ---------------
1          2014-08-20 14:08:31.280 2014-08-20 14:08:33.450 72216        15
```

Where VoteTypeId 1 is "accepted an answer" - which is, as shown: a +15 reputation change.

Basically, somebody accepted your answer, then unaccepted it 2 seconds later:

- maybe they mis-clicked the first time
- maybe another answer was *even better* than yours

Note: we advertise rep *increases* through the realtime updates, but we don't advertise *decreases* as aggressively - for those, you sometimes need to wait until the next page load.

If I look back a few more days, there are indeed a few similar - some "accepted an answer", some "upvoted" - but cancelled within a few seconds. So yes, sometimes people change their minds for whatever reason.

Comment: Perfect! That should be it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JacobVlijm the good news is: you haven't ever done this to anyone else ;p

Comment: Or I did it too fast to notice :)

Comment: @Jacob the database knows all ;)