# Seemingly "unregistered" reputation change?

Tags: support

This morning, opening the computer, I found a reputation change of `+92`, which is nice, but kind of a strange figure. It even appears differently on different windows.

[image]

[image]

The `+100` I can find. The (appearant) `-8` however is a weird figure; *seems* like 4 "old" questions I edited might have been removed, but I can find nothing whatsoever about it in my history. Also if [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11819/changing-reputation-somtimes-it-goes-up-then-down-again) was the case, or simply an un-upvote, it would be like `-10` or `-15`.

Although I have the feeling I am overlooking something, I am just curious what might be the cause.

Comment: Easiest method is to check http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/reputation  Btw: I had that too the other day but mine was a undownvote (so easy to spot)

Comment: @Rinzwind That is a nice overview!  It makes the mystery however bigger, nothing about the -8 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your reputation tab, Community has been tidying up - 4 old questions that you have edited in the past (back in April/May '14) have been removed.

This period was when you were officially a newbie ... and earning 2 rep per edit.

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it, but it doesn't show in my overview (yet). Overview only shows "Yesterday" at the moment :).

Comment: @JacobVlijm There's a little checkbox at the bottom of your reputation page that says something like "show reputation changes from deleted posts" or something like that. You may need to check it.

Comment: @Seth I found it! And there are the four deleted posts :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A -8 can be a zero-score (+1/-1) answer getting deleted - perhaps the question got cleaned because it didn't have a positive score or any answers with a positive score.

Comment: That would clarify it, but wouldn't it be in the overview? Deleted "old" edited questions normally do.

Comment: I don't remember. This has happened to me, but not recently enough for it to show up in "deleted recent answers".